# nginx: try to serve minified files first

Tags: optimization, url-rewriting, nginx, webserver

I'm trying to optimize my websites by minifying the css, js, svg and whatnot.

This however meddles with my codebase and I would like to keep the original files around. I've set up git to autmoatically minify any `css|js|svg` to `min.css|min.js|min.svg` but I'm not editing every php or html file that links to these files to use the `.min.` extension.

To mend this, I was thinking that I could set up nginx serve the minified versions of the files automatically when a request for the non-minified files is done using the `try_files` directives and use the non-minified files as a backup if they don't exist.

This is some pseudo-configuration to elaborate what I mean:

```
location \.(css|js|svg) {
      try_files $minified_uri $uri;  
}
```

but I have no clue on how to get the `$minified_uri` here (e.g. `/some/style.min.css` is served when `/some/style.css` is requested).

Also, if you think this approach is really bad, please be free to tell me why and show me some alternatives!

Comment: I honestly think just replace the lines in code is faster. You can probably spend 10 mins figuring out how to do batch replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fairly easy to accomplish using regex variables:

```
location ~ ^(.+)\.(css|js|svg)$ {
    try_files $1.min.$2 $uri =404;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't guarantee that it would work but I guess you can give it a try

```
location ~ (?<name>[^/]*)\.(?<extention>css|js|svg) {
    try_files $name.min.$extention $name.$extention;  
}
```